# I have a 2D array of custom objects. Must I instantiate each in Java?

Tags: java, android, object, multidimensional-array

```
    dmap = new Tile[maxW][maxH];
    for (int y = 0; y < maxH; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < maxW; ++x)
            dmap[x][y] = new Tile();
```

This is slow despite each `Tile` only having an `int` member which anyway is made 0. I have not written a constructor for `Tile()`. Can I improve or should I go back to C++?

`maxW` and `maxH` are both 255, and my environment is the Android emulator.

I don't think it is this code that is slow anymore. My `Log.i()` statements have gone missing from the LogCat view... I pute one in for each `y` in the above initialisation code.

Comment: 65k objects creation should not be that slow - unless you keep doing it every 10 ms...

Comment: What is "slow"? Did you profile your code?

Comment: Yes, you must initialize every object. How is it slow? How much time does it take? It's slow compared to what?

Comment: @Puce It took 2+ minutes and the `onClick()` method has not returned, I force Closed this time...

Comment: If your `Tile` having just int why do you need this object?

Comment: @John: what does your `Tile` class look like? Maybe it's constructing the `super`object that takes time or lots of memory allocation.

Comment: @mishadoff just method encapsualtion.

Comment: I added the android tag to your question.

Comment: @John it is trade-off between objects and privitives. Try to using external methods for working with your ints if you have a lot of objects

Comment: The fact that it is the android emulator makes a difference - have you checked the log when you get the force close? Could it be a memory issue?

Comment: @assylias My logs have gone from the LogCat window altogether now... That would be me clicking pause in the SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to initialize the array with objects. By default it will contain null values, and you can keep it like this, if this is OK in your case.

Comment: null? I'm from C++. would that mean null as in useless, or null as in zero intialiased? Sorry but I really need a useable base object instantiated.

Comment: null as in no object you could work with. This could be usefull if you'd prefer late initialization or if you don't need all of the objects (then you might consider a sparse array, though).

Answer (score 1):

If you want each array element to contain a valid object, then yes, you'll need to create an object to go in each array element. However, depending on what you're trying to achieve, things which might help:

Lazy initialisation: you could wrap the array, and only create a Tile when it's needed, leaving the array mostly populated with nulls.

Move your abstraction: instead of an array of Tile objects, possibly have a TileMap object, containing a 2D array of ints (which won't require construction, and will default to zero), and have that return the appropriate Tile for the given tile index.

You say all Tiles contain only an int, at the moment. Do you want different tiles with the same int value to be distinct objects? A lot of the expense here is creating the new object, not assigning it to the array index. Pre-creating your instances - or possibly using an enum of Tile instances - will mean this overhead doesn't need to be repeated.